# Notifications of Suggested Edits: The Orange Like Number Next to Review Button

Tags: discussion, bug, suggested-edits

When I am done with my 20 review of suggested edits in a day, I still get notifications for that. Don't you think that it can be considered as a bug? I think that it is better, when someone has reviewed all 20 suggested edits in a day then there shouldn't be any more notifications for that user in that day!

In fact, when some user is not allowed to review any more in a particular day, then why notifications of suggested edits should come to that user? It is pointless!

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: I am telling that when some is not allowed to review any more on a day or even some one like you, then why he\she should be notified! It is meaningless, I think! :)

Comment: Of course It is meaningless, but *what can't be cured, must be endured*.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: So I wrote this thread that maybe some cure could be found by developers! :)

Comment: A more annoying issue regarding suggested edits is that if you click on the notification, there's only about a 5% chance that you will actually get to review something.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice for this to be removed.

Comment: Are you talking about a suggested edit to your own post? There is a feature request on meta.SE: [After reviewing 50 edits I can't approve an edit to my own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139286/after-reviewing-50-edits-i-cant-approve-an-edit-to-my-own-answer)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: No, I didn't mean this! Also, I didn't know that there is a such a problem too! :)

Comment: I thought you were talking about your posts because you mention *notification*. (Judging by the - now deleted - answer, it seems that I was not the only one who understood your question this way.) So by notification you meant the numbers which are sometimes (if there are many reviews) shown near the review button?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! :) What should I call them!? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, but by design and the feature-request to change it got declined long ago [Don't display pending edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes)  (the situation slightly changed and there is another request [Don't display suggested edit counter if you've exhausted your suggested edit votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144370/dont-display-suggested-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-vot)  but I think the main reasoning there still applies).

The theoretical point to note is that it is intended not as a notification but as an information. That counter is not a call to take immediate action, but it merely informs you that it might make sense to visit the review-queue. I know that for suggested edits it  might not really much feel like this in practice, but 10k+ users get the (cached and approximate) count of all review tasks there, to them on this site there is basically always some number there.

The practical point to note is that it would be difficult to change this, or maybe difficult is not the right word, but rather it would be expensive performance-wise to determine the number on  a per-user basis rather then to show one number to all concerned. Note that if you suggest edits yourself you will also increase the counter while you cannot possibly review them.

**To sum this up:** Treat the counter as information not as notification, and ignore it  when it is not relevant to you at this point in time, for example as you know you are out of reviews.

Comment: Regarding the performance-cost, can it really not be delegated to the individual user's browser? As in, the site reports the actual queue instead of just the counter (still relatively low-cost), and the browser judges whether anything should be presented?